# React Native - If everything in array contains

Tags: react-native

So I am building an app for my business. This app needs to check an array of devices to see if Lost Mode has been enabled. If 1 device has lostMode on then it needs to set variables, however if ALL of them are false then I need it to set all the variables back.

This function is running when I do a pull down to refresh.

I can get the first part working, but I can figure out how to check to make sure ALL the values in the array are false.

```
checkDevices = () => {
    storeDevices.map((item) => {
      if (item.security.lost_mode_enabled === 'true') {
        setLostDevice(item);
        setLostMode(true);
        setLostDeviceTabInfo(item);
        setSelectedOption(item);
        setSelected(true);
      }
    });
  };
```

I need it to check the storeDevices array after the first check to see if everything is false.

We run an API in the background that flips it off and the App needs to be able to refresh that.

Comment: I'm confused by "If ALL of them are false then I need to set all the variables back" If you don't encounter a device with lost mode enabled, then you haven't changed any data.

Comment: So the app checks if the device is in lost mode. If it is, it selects that item and then sets the app into a state called Lost mode to prevent the user of the phone from doing anything else.

Comment: I need to implement a pull-down to refresh to do this check again, to run through the loop, and I need it to reset the variables if the devices ALL show false.

Comment: when you say "reset the variables", what are you resetting them to? You mention that storeDevices is an array. Where is the data inside that array coming from? Is there an API call which returns a list of devices and you're using that to update storeDevices? A lot more context is required before someone can begin to help you with the problem. Perhaps share more of the code? For instance, what does "setLostDevice" do?